# How to trigger macro when comment is modified?

Tags: excel, vba

Is there a way to trigger a macro that would resize comments (I don't like the way autosize=true is doing it) whenever a comment is modified in Excel?  Everything I'm reading says comment changes won't trigger any type of worksheet change event.

Comment: You can change the size of the cell comments (manually or with code), but there is no event that is triggered.

Comment: So no way to change the size of the comment each time I edit the text, aside from what Excel does when autosize = true?

Comment: If you could also edit (even just enter/exit a cell itself), you could use the `Worksheet Change()` function.

Comment: You could include code to change the size of the comment box for the cell when the content of the cell itself changes, but I dont see how that would do you much good.

Comment: Any way to rig it so that when I exit the comment (escape twice) it automatically jumps into and out of the parent cell?  Otherwise I have to hit escape twice, then F2, then enter every time.

Comment: Maybe you could make a UserForm for comment editing that does a bunch of things when you click OK on the form? Granted, it's a bit more work...

Comment: You might be able to use the `SelectionChange` event, but it'll still be a bit of a hack.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something along these lines, its a bit clunky as not fully tested as late here now :)

```
Dim rPrev As Excel.Range
Dim sPrev As String
Dim cPrev As Comment

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

If Not rPrev Is Nothing Then
    If Not cPrev Is Nothing Then
        cPrev.Shape.Width = Len(rPrev.Comment.Text) * 5
    End If
End If

Set rPrev = Target

If Not Target.Comment Is Nothing Then
    Set cPrev = Target.Comment
    sPrev = cPrev.Text
End If

End Sub
```